# Place frame in the correct position

Tags: plotting, legending, frame

I am plotting different waves (computed numerically and analytically) and, for that, I have used the following code:

```
Plot[Sin[t], {t, 0, 50}, PlotStyle -> Red, Axes -> False, Frame -> True, PlotTheme -> "Classic", FrameLabel -> {"t", "\[Phi] (0, t)"}, FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, 25], 
 PlotLegends -> Placed[{"Exact."}, {{1, 0.56}}], PlotLabel -> Style[Framed["w = 1, k = 0", 
 RoundingRadius -> 5], 20, Black, Background -> Lighter[White]]
```

what gives:

[image]

As you can notice, the frame that contains some specifications is not centered. How can I place it in the correct position (centered)? I have attempted to use the Placed instruction but it doesn't work (or I've not been able to write properly the instruction).

Answer (score 3):

One possibility is to use `Labeled`:

```
Labeled[
 Plot[Sin[t]
  , {t, 0, 50}
  , PlotStyle -> Red
  , Axes -> False
  , Frame -> True
  , PlotTheme -> "Classic"
  , FrameLabel -> {"t", "\[Phi] (0, t)"}
  , FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, 16]
  , PlotLegends -> Placed[{"Exact."}, {{1, 0.56}}]
  ]
 , Framed[
  Style["w = 1, k = 0", 20, Black]
  , FrameStyle -> {Black, AbsoluteThickness[1.2]}
  , RoundingRadius -> 5
  , Background -> Lighter[White]
  ]
 , Top
 ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

use `FrameLabel` since you set Frame to True. You were using `FrameLabel` And also using `PlotLabel`. Why mix the two? `FrameLabel` can do all of these. The top frame label now acts as the overall Plot Label.

`FrameLabel` is also automatically centered on each edge.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Plot[Sin[t], {t, 0, 50},
 PlotStyle -> Red,
 Axes -> False,
 Frame -> True,
 PlotTheme -> "Classic",
 FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, 25],
 PlotLegends -> Placed[{"Exact."}, {{1, 0.56}}],
 FrameLabel -> {{"ϕ (0, t)", Automatic}, {"t", 
    Style[Framed["w = 1, k = 0", RoundingRadius -> 5], 20, Black, 
     Background -> Lighter[White]]}},
 ImageSize -> 500
 ]
```